# sql query complication for activity/news feed on a social network

Tags: mysql

im currently learning a variety of different things, so to do this im currently building myself a little social networking site and its getting there. I just have couple of things left to do and one of them is a activity/news feed or what ever you want to call it. its simple enough to show your own posts on your profile feed. but on the index page where it will be your own posts plus the posts of your friends, that's what im struggling with. firstly i have a table for `friends` which have columns `user_one` & `user_two` and if there well your friends if your number is in one of them and another user is in the other one. The query i originally tried to pull the posts made by a few different users was

```
SELECT * FROM `post`, `friends` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND (`friends`.`user_one` = $user_id OR `friends`.`user_two` = $user_id)
```

from this it should, select posts and friends where the posts user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] AND  where user_one OR user_two in the friends table = $_SESSION['user_id']. this should get any post made by the OTHER user_id that is in the same row (in the friends table) that as $_SESSION['user_id'] ...

But the problem is what is happening is its pulling up a result that instead of being just the one post as i hoped for, it pulls up repeats. i think this is down to the fact that its pulling up the double results because its like ..say im user 1.. and user 2 and 3 are my friends, well it pulls one result for user 2 & one result for user 3 ...

What i want is it to just pull up the one result to show on user 1's activity feed that are posted by me and my 'friends'... can someone advise me on how id best do this? If anyone can understand me lol ...

cheers

Richard

Comment: Why does `friends` have *three* user_id columns?

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining both tables, which is why you get duplicates.

I would write this query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `post`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `friends` 
               WHERE (`friends`.`user_one` = $user_id AND `post`.`user_id` = `friends`.`user_two`)
                OR   (`friends`.`user_two` = $user_id AND `post`.`user_id` = `friends`.`user_one`)
              )
```